# How to fix this iterative python code and reduce repetition?

Tags: python

This snippet of code was supposed to generate a random number which represents a question. The number generator generates numbers from 1 through 10. But if the number is not in the list of numbers `"numlist"` it is supposed to generate another number. This is supposed to make it so that the program won't ask the same question twice. using `numlist.remove()` did not work for this purpose. What will work? Or, what is a better method.

Also, I want to know how to make it so that there is less repetition in the code (loop?).

```
def roll():
    var = random.randint(1,10)
    if var not in numlist:
        roll()

    elif var == 1:
        numlist.remove(1)
        q1()
    elif var == 2:
        numlist.remove(2)
        q2()
    elif var == 3:
        numlist.remove(3)
        q3()
    elif var == 4:
        numlist.remove(4)
        q4()
    elif var == 5:
        numlist.remove(5)
        q5()
    elif var ==6:
        numlist.remove(6)
        q6()
    elif var == 7:
        numlist.remove(7)
        q7()
    elif var == 8:
        numlist.remove(8)
        q8()
    elif var == 9:
        numlist.remove(9)
        q9()
    elif var == 10:
        numlist.remove(10)
        q10()
```

Comment: How about just `numlist.remove(var)`?

Comment: But there is also the q*()

Comment: will you always end up using all 10 questions, just in a random order?

Comment: Why are there 10 functions with almost the same name? I bet if you showed them there is some way to combine them into one

Comment: There are 10 individual functions so that each question is a function, where hints can be given, answers can be displayed etc. I wanted each question to have a tailor made function. Of course, I'm sure there's a way to have one large function that encompasses each. I have to note though, this program is not intended to only have 10 questions. I'm planning on putting in tons of questions from past tests. @Volatility: Yes.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57: If there are going to be more questions that makes it all the more important that each one does not get its own function. (What if you want to change slightly how questions, hints and answers are given? You're going to change dozens or even hundreds of functions?) Instead, you should store all the questions as a data structure (a simple example would be a list of 3-tuples, each of which looks like `(question, hints, answer)`, though a better approach would be for each to be an instance of a Question class) and then have a single function that asks, gives hints, and answers.

Comment: @David Robinson I had initially thought about making a 'database' like you mentioned, which a function would be able to access in order to ask questions. However, I had no idea how to do that. This project was to get back into learning Python, so I wanted to use only what I knew how to do then ask for help here, since you guys always have tons of great ideas. I'm off to research and try your suggestions, then I'll pick the best answer. I like the data structure and class structure ideas in particular, but I haven't yet delved into classes and data structures. So, research time.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57: I just posted an answer that describes in detail my object-oriented suggestion. I hope you look over it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping one function per question is not a good strategy. What if you want to change slightly how questions, hints and answers are given? You're going to change dozens or even hundreds of functions?

A much better approach is an object-oriented one- for example, where each question is an object of the `Question` class. For example:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, hints, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.hints = hints
        self.answer = answer

    def ask_question(self):
        print "Here is your question:"
        print self.question

    def give_hint(self):
        if len(self.hints) == 0:
            print "That's all the hints I have!"
        else:
            print self.hints.pop(0)

     def guess(self, guess):
        if guess == self.answer:
            print "You guessed correctly!"
        else:
            print "No, try again!"
```

Any behavior that you originally encapsulated in the question function (limiting the number of guesses, limited amount of time, displaying in a certain format, whatever) would all be handled by methods of the `Question` class. In the meantime, all the information specific to one question would be held in the data members (in this case `question`, `hints` and `answers`, although there could be other variables) that are specific to that question.

You would create a question like this:

```
q1 = Question("How many roads must a man walk down?", ["Think Douglas Adams.", "It's more than 40 and less than 50"], "42")
```

Or better yet, create them from a tab delimited file, where the file is something like:

```
How many roads must a man walk down?    Think Douglas Adams./It's more than 40 and less than 50    42
```

And they are created like:

```
questions = []
with open("questions.txt") as inf:
    for l in inf:
        question, hints, answer = l[:-1].split("\t")
        questions.append(Question(question, hints.split("/"), answer))
```

Then your main function would call methods of the `Question`, which encapsulate its question-asking behavior. This would keep you from ever having to repeat code (all the code exists only in one place: the methods of the `Question` object) and would keep all your questions in a flexible format.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to use the numbers only for dispatching. The same result (calling each of 10 functions in random order) can be achieved without going through numbers first, like so:

```
import random

def roll():
    qs = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10]
    random.shuffle(qs)
    for q in qs:
        yield q

# ...

for rolled in roll():
    rolled()
```

By not invoking the `q#()` functions directly and instead yielding them, they can be invoked whenever it's convenient for the caller.

Comment: Another option is to repeatedly use `random.choice` to select a question and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def roll():
    var = random.randint(1,10)
    if var not in numlist:
        roll()
    else:
        numlist.remove(var)
        call_me = getattr(module, 'q%s'% var)
```

Comment: Unnecessary (and potentially catastrophic, although that's very unlikely) recursion.  I'd use `random.choice` instead.

Comment: @Trufa is right, you should rewrite `q` to be more generic, so its one function and not 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can, but instead of having 10 functions q1()..q10 I would make a function that accepts a parameter this way:

```
def roll():
    var = random.randint(1,10)
    if var not in numlist:
        roll()
    else:
        numlist.remove(var)
        q(var)
```

You should also be checking if `numlist` is empty (just in case).

Also, there is a very unlikely chance that the random int is never the one in the list causing a stack overflow, with 10 ints very unlikely though, but if you want to make sure this can't happen you should:

make a list with the choices:

```
choices = range(1,11)
```

you should use [choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to chose from that list:

```
var = random.choice(choices)
```

and then remove that choice:

```
choices.remove(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the functions in a list, shuffle the list and then pop out the result question function:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> l = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> qfunc = l.pop()
```