# How to check multiple else condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python script with will read each ip from file and install agent on that ip using password, there are 5-6 passwords and if one password does't work it should try with other all passwords one by one.
some code of my script for one password is:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./linux_autodisc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        p1 = str(p.communicate())
                        if '1 devices were successfully added/updated' in p1:
                                print ('Sucessfull Completed Ip: ' +line)
                                f6 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt","a")
                                f6.write("\n"+line)
                                f6.close()
                        else: 
                             print "Unsuccessfull"
```

How i can include multiple else to run script for 5-6 passwords and for last else it should return tried all password and not successful.

Comment: Thought about putting your passwords into a list, iterate over it and set it. If its set stop the iteration.

Comment: You can use if...elif.....else

Comment: What is condition required for elif in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To keep your code cleaner i would advice to extract a function like this:

```
    def try_password(password):
      ``code that uses the password``

    for password in password_array:
       successful = try_password(password)
       if successful:
          break
```

The stacking of else statements will make your code harder to read/understand, and it will complicate future changes.

This is my proposal for your script:

```
##Reading values from SucessfullIp.txt
with open('/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt') as f:
  ips = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)

password_list = ["password1","password2"]

##Reading Unique Ip's values 
with open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/Unique.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
            line = line.rstrip()
            ## Comparing unique ip's if ip is already has scanned
            if line in ips:
                    print('{}: Ip is Already Tried: '.format(line))
            else:
            ##Creating inventory.cfg file on the fly for each ip
                for password in password_list:
                    if try_password(password):
                        print ('Sucessfull Completed Ip: ' +line)
                        f6 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt","a")
                        f6.write("\n"+line)
                        f6.close()
                        break
                    else:
                        print "Unsuccessfull for {}".format(password) ## dont break and check others

## Extracted function to use password
## This could perhaps be optimized by extracting repetative tasks (depends on usage/performance)
def try_password(password):
    f3 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/inventory.cfg", "w")
    print "Processing Ip: " + line

    ##here we are giving credentials                
    write_string = "[device42_access]"  + "\n" +
          "base_url = https://1.8.0.3"  + "\n" +
          "username = uname"  + "\n" +
          "secret = abcd"  + "\n" +
          "[discover]"  + "\n" +
          "cpu= true"  + "\n" +
          "hardware = true"  + "\n" +
          "memory = true"  + "\n" +
          "[access]"+ "\n" +
          "credentials = username:{}"
    f3.write(write_string.format(password))
    f3.close()
    p = subprocess.Popen(["./d42_linux_autodisc_v620"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) ##This script will require inventory.cfg file created above
    p1 = str(p.communicate())
    return '1 devices were successfully added/updated' in p1
```

Comment: I do agree.
Some foor for thoughts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431118/how-to-fix-this-iterative-python-code-and-reduce-repetition

Comment: Although the return-statement would work, perhaps it would be wise to check if there is another way to validate if a device was added/updated since this is very founrable to language/grammar changes

Comment: You have f.write but f3 everywhere else.